# commit inside git submodule foreach

Tags: git, sh, git-submodules, git-config

I have a git repository that has a submodule. Generally I'm committing the repo and submodule with the same commit message. Currently when I want to commit my repo and submodule, I'm doing the following:

```
cd submodule
git add --all
git commit -m "message"
git push
cd ..
git add --all
git commit -m "message"
git push
```

I would like an alias that allows me to do this with a single command e.g.

```
git commit-including-submodule "blah"
```

Sounds simple, but I'm having a few issues with the alias. The closest I've got is the following:

```
[alias]
   commit-including-submodule = "!f() { \
         if [ -u $1 ]; then \
            echo "commit message required"; \
         else \
            git submodule foreach 'git add --all && git commit -m \"$1\"'; \
            git add --all && git commit -m $1; \
            echo "success"; \
         fi; \
       }; f"
```

However the commit message in the submodule is

> git add --all && git commit -m "$1"

Yes that is the actual commit message, which seems a bit odd. I haven't been able to figure this out. Can anyone please help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may not be successfully escaping the quotes.  I think this should work.

```
[alias]
   commit-including-submodule = "!f() { \
         if [ -u $1 ]; then \
            echo "commit message required"; \
         else \
            git submodule foreach 'git add --all && git commit -m '"$1"'; \
            git add --all && git commit -m $1; \
            echo "success"; \
         fi; \
       }; f"
```